# Convert int/string to byte array with length n

Tags: arrays, go, type-conversion, byte

How can I convert a value like 5 or "Testing" to an array of type byte with a fixed length of n byte?

Edit:

I want to represent the number 5 in bits. I know that it's 101, but I want it represented as array with a length of for example 6 bytes, so 000000 ....

Comment: This question is too hypothetical to answer. Add more context please.  Maybe I'm missing something here... Also this "array of type byte with a fixed length of n byte" makes no sense at all.  the number of bytes used to represent 5 and number of bytes used to represent "Testing" CANNOT be represented by the same number of bytes regardless of programming language.

Comment: @OkezieE Made it more concrete :)

Comment: This question doesn't really make send ... even after making more concrete!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: This one is simple as you seem to be okay with a non-bijective representation: `func convert(_ interface{}) [6]byte { return [6]byte{} }` . It's neither injective nor surjective, but hey, I't answers your question. But I admit it wont solve any problem. Nobody understands what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here but all I can say is assuming you simply want to represent characters in the binary form of it's ASCII code, you can pad the binary representation with zeros.  For example if the set number of characters you want is 10, then encoding the letter `a` (with ASCII code of `97`) in binary will be `1100001`, padded to 10 characters will be `0001100001`, but that is for a single character to be encoded.  The encoding of a string, which is made up of multiple characters will be a set of these 10 digit binary codes which represent the corresponding character in the ASCII table. The encoding of data is important so that the system knows how to interpret the binary data. Then there is also endianness depending on the system architecture - but that's less of an issue these days with more old and modern processors like the ARM processors being bi-endian.

> So forget about representing the number 5 and the string "WTF" using
>   the same number of bytes - it makes the brain hurt. Stop it.

A bit more reading on character encoding will be great.
Start here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
Then this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
Then brain hurt - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness